# Why does this series diverge? What's wrong with my reasoning?

Tags: divergent-series

So I have this series

$$\sum_{j=2}^{\infty} \frac{-(2j-3)(j-3)}{(5j-8)(4j+1)}$$

I figured by reasoning that with the leading coefficients: -2J^2 / 20 j^2

the bottom would win out if the J went to infinity.

Also it is ratio of 1/10 so I thought the series would converge.

So why does this series diverge?

Can someone use the Cauchy Condensation, Comparison Test, or Ratio test.

I haven't started reviewing integral test or the other tests yet.

Comment: I think they call it the "divergence test" or whatever, but the terms don't tend to 0, which is a clear necessary condition for convergence (via the Cauchy criterion)

Comment: The terms as you have observed are nearly equal to $-1/10$ after some point. Do you think $(-1/10) + (-1/10)  + (-1/10)  + \cdots $ converges? Point number 2 is: revisit the ratio test - carefully.

Comment: The ratio test refers to the ratio *between successive terms*, not the value of the individual terms themselves.  The ratio between successive terms tends to unity as $j$ increases without bound, so the ratio test is inconclusive.  (The series itself clearly is unbounded, since the individual terms do not go to $0$, as Nitin observed.)

Answer (score 3):

It diverges: for any convergent series, the general term tends to $0$. Here the general term tends to $-\dfrac1{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

The expression
$$ -\frac{(2j-3)(j-3)}{(5j-8)(4j+1)}=-\frac{(2-3/j)(1-3/j)}{(5-8/j)(4+1/j)}$$ has a limit of $-(2)(1)/(5)(4)=-1/10$ as $j\to \infty.$ Since the terms of the series do not tend to $0,$ the series has no limit.

Answer (score 0):

I see the flaw in my reasoning. I have done the ratio test and cauchy condesation test and found that it diverges.